# A poetic day of the week

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, history

**The genius discovered that the egg could stand**

In front of the sons of Jacob,

I promptly admit my wrongdoings.

Benjamin was never one of them, but two of his name brothers were.

The little boy was hard as metal!

---

**Disney wedding for real!**

Bollinger and Salinger invited to a party,

But since my moral inventory,

Has liberated me from slavery,

I now have IT in the valley.

---

**The European help was born!**

Making an international call to the captain of the flying ship,

I am now sober to understand that,

Hate hates not to hate hate

But we will rock you!

---

**What day of the week?**

I would be in the first prime in the early twenties,

Even to admit that I am powerless,

but holding my Teddy,

I will never be as strong as Superman!

---

> Solve the puzzle, and answer the only question correctly!

Hint 1:

> The flying captain IS the One to set the standards

Hint 2:

> How many sons did Jacob have?

Hint 3:

> **ab.cd.efgh** 
>  ab 
>  cd 
>  ef 
>  gh

Hint 4:

> Each line in a verse represents a two-digit number

Hint 5:

> **Disney wedding for real** is referring to the wedding date for a historical woman which is also a Disney princess.

Hint 6 (very strong hint):

> Second verse; **Disney wedding for real (Pocahontas) = 05.04.1614**, Salinger party (TV-serie: Party of five) = 05, moral inventory ( ??) = 04, and so on...

Comment: Is some knowledge of popular culture required to solve this? (You might want to add the [tag:trivia] tag if so.)

Comment: Is the phrase "but two of his name brothers was." written as intended?

Comment: @ClamSoapMan no, fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The day is

> Saturday (23rd January 2636)

---

**The genius discovered that the egg could stand**

> Jacob has **12** sons named Reuben, Simeon, Levi, Judah, Dan, Naphtali, Gad, Asher, Issachar, Zebulun, Joseph, and Benjamin.
>  Reference to step **10** of the Alcoholics Anonymous 12 Steps which states
>  *Continued to take personal inventory and when we were wrong promptly admitted it.*
> The 3rd line gives us Franklin Pierce the **14**th President of the USA
> **92** Little Boy was a Uranium (element 92) bomb 
>  so using the date code from the hints we have **12th October 1492** - the date that Christopher Columbus landed in America (the original Egg of Columbus)

---

**Disney wedding for real!**

> Salinger is one of the characters in Party of **Five** 
>  The **4**th Step is *Made a searching and fearless moral inventory of ourselves* 
>  Line 3 refers to the emancipation and Abraham Lincoln (President **#16**)
> Silicon (**14**) Valley 
>  gives the date of Pocahontas' wedding on **5th April 1614**

---

**The European help was born!**

> The international dialling code of the Netherlands is +**31** for our flying captain
> Line 2 is a reference to / an alternative wording of Step **12** of recovery which is *Having had a spiritual awakening as the result of these steps, we tried to carry this message to alcoholics, and to practice these principles in all our affairs.* 
>  In opposite terms *love loves to love love* in Joyce's novel so we get Ulysses S. Grant (**18**)
>  and a wonderful song by Queen led by Freddie giving us **80**
>  the date is **31st December 1880** the birthday of General Marshall, Churchill's "organiser of victory"

---

**What day of the week?**

> The first prime in the early 20s is 23 
>  *We admitted we were powerless over alcohol - that our lives had become unmanageable* is step **1** on the road to recovery
>  Teddy Roosevelt was the **26**th president and Superman's element, krypton, is element **36** so the date would be **23rd January 2636**...a Saturday

Comment: Good try! Wednesday is wrong answer however. The pattern of the date is the same in all four verses, but the weekdays in itself is not part of any pattern

Comment: Verse 1 and 2 are however interpreted correctly. But what about verse 3? And you have something wrong in verse 4 as well...

Comment: Hmmm ok well had a go at 3 now - can't work out the president...unless they aren't presidents

Comment: What country do the captain of the flying ship come from?

Comment: The two last lines of verse 3 are both referring to real lines of poetry...

Comment: Hint 1 is referring to the ISO date standard used in the country of the flying captain...

Comment: I'd assume that the flying ship is the [Flying Dutchman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Dutchman), although I could be wrong

Comment: The line "The European helper was born" is referring to the complete date of verse 3 and could be used as a confirmation whether the other lines are correct...

Comment: help or helper?

Comment: Oops! Revealed a bit too much there... Yes, a person responsible for European help...:-)

Comment: We will rock you! What element in the periodic table is associated with that...?

Comment: It is a song...

Comment: By Queen...ah dammit...we weren't looking for the band, clever. It's mercury

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise on the recovery steps on several of the verses, as well. And the hate-line is somehow linking to a famous quote from literature...

Comment: I am now sober to understand, is step 12, giving the birth date of US secretary George Marshall. Teddy Roosevelt is correct, so it is just to say the weekday of the last date, and you are finished:-)

Comment: The Marshall help, was a plan to financially help Europe rebuild after WW2